# Client+server in Twisted

Tags: python, proxy, twisted

I have Client and multiclient Server, they're simply replacing messages. Some messages have to be changed during connection, so I have to create some sort of "Proxy", which will be changing and passing msgs.
It will be looking like this:
Client --> Proxy (change msg) --> Server --> Proxy (change msg) --> Client --> etc...

I've found great lib Twisted. There are many examples, but I don't now how to change e.g.
http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/doc/core/examples/chatserver.py
to open connection with Server, when new Client comes.

Any help will  be appreciated.